# PDF print out for answers

Tags: feature-request

Are there any plans to provide an option in the settings to print out a post-with or without the comments- as a PDF file without all the clutter of links around?

Comment: You might see if there is a recommendation on [softwarerecs.se]. I have software that came with my printer that let's me print only some parts of any web page.

Comment: I have not tried but I find a lot of extensions for Firefox. There might be one good for the job. However, I find it convenient to have a feature such as this, implemented on many websites. It seems I got the answer. Thanks ColleenV.

Comment: I recall that there was something on Stackapps for this called "Stack Printer". Sadly, I'm on mobile and can't give you the links at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Just to capture what is in the comments: There is a [Stack Printer](http://www.stackprinter.com/about) web app that can print out questions with all of the comments and answers in a printer friendly format.

There is a "[bookmarklet](http://www.yourdictionary.com/bookmarklet)", or a short script that can be executed from a bookmark in a browser, on the About page. If you add the URL to your favorites/bookmarks bar in your browser, it will create a printer friendly version of the current question you're reading when you click it. Just right click on [the Bookmarklet link](http://javascript:(function()%7Bvar%20re%20=%20new%20RegExp('%5Ehttp://(.*?)%5C.com/questions/([0-9]%20)/');var%20group%20=%20re.exec(window.location.href);if%20(group!=null)%7Bvar%20service%20=%20group[1];var%20questionid=group[2];window.open('http://www.stackprinter.com/export?format=HTML&service='%20service%20'&question='%20questionid)%7Delse%7Balert('Attention:%20question%20id%20not%20found!')%7D%7D)()) and choose the appropriate bookmark function for your browser from the context menu.